# how to fetch array of documents from other collections for each document in a collection using lookup mongodb hapijs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lookup, hapi.js

I am using MongoDB and HapiJs
I have 3 mongo db collections as follows:

```
companies: [
    {_id: "autogeneratedId", name: "companyname1"},
    {_id: "autogeneratedId", name: "companyname2"}
]
employees: [
    {_id: "autogeneratedId", salary: 10000, employeename: "employeename1", "company_id": "_id of company"}, 
    {_id: "autogeneratedId", salary: 50000, employeename: "employeename2", "company_id": "_id of company"}, 
    {_id: "autogeneratedId", salary: 25000, employeename: "employeename3", "company_id": "_id of company"}
]
products: [
    {_id: "autogeneratedId", price: 900, productname: "productname1", "company_id": "_id of company"}, 
    {_id: "autogeneratedId", price: 400, productname: "productname2", "company_id": "_id of company"}, 
    {_id: "autogeneratedId", price: 500, productname: "productname3", "company_id": "_id of company"}
]
```

I am trying to fetch the list of companies from `companies` collection. Now along with the list of `companies` I also want to fetch the list of products and employees of each corresponding company from collections `products` and `employees` based on _id of `companies` collection. Here is the code I am trying

```
db.getCollection('companies').aggregate([
                {
                  $lookup:
                    {
                      from: "employees",
                      localField: "_id",
                      foreignField: "company_id",
                      as: "employees_array"
                    }
               },
                {
                  $lookup:
                    {
                      from: "products",
                      localField: "_id",
                      foreignField: "company_id",
                      as: "products_array"
                    }
               },
            ])
```

But for some reason the above code returns an empty array in products_array and employees_array. So, can anyone tell me whats wrong am I doing over here?

Also in employees_array and products_array I want to fetch only data based on a condition like employees having salary >= 10000 and products having price >= 500. So how do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you edit your post and insert actual values for _id and company_id ?

Comment: I have exact same structure and values as in Alex P answer. And expected result is also the same as Alex P has described in her answer. But for some reason I am not getting the results in `products_array` and `employees_array`. The `company_id` in `products` and `employees` is a reference to mongodb autogenerated `_id` field of `companies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the documents that I added:

**companies**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da"),
    "name" : "companyname1"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98dc"),
    "name" : "companyname2"
}
```

**employees**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a34564c9beb3178555e990d"),
    "salary" : 10000,
    "employeename" : "employeename1",
    "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a34564c9beb3178555e990f"),
    "salary" : 50000,
    "employeename" : "employeename2",
    "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a34564c9beb3178555e9911"),
    "salary" : 25000,
    "employeename" : "employeename3",
    "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98dc")
}
```

**products**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3456929beb3178555e991e"),
    "price" : 900,
    "productname" : "productname1",
    "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3456929beb3178555e9920"),
    "price" : 400,
    "productname" : "productname2",
    "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98dc")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3456929beb3178555e9922"),
    "price" : 500,
    "productname" : "productname3",
    "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da")
}
```

When applying only your query:

```
db.getCollection('companies').aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: "employees",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "company_id",
            as: "employees_array"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "company_id",
            as: "products_array"
        }
    }
])
}
```

If your fields are named as you posted in your question then you should get results. Look for some type or something. I get the following results (which seem correct from what you describe):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da"),
    "name" : "companyname1",
    "employees_array" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a34564c9beb3178555e990d"),
            "salary" : 10000,
            "employeename" : "employeename1",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a34564c9beb3178555e990f"),
            "salary" : 50000,
            "employeename" : "employeename2",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da")
        }
    ],
    "products_array" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a3456929beb3178555e991e"),
            "price" : 900,
            "productname" : "productname1",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a3456929beb3178555e9922"),
            "price" : 500,
            "productname" : "productname3",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98da")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98dc"),
    "name" : "companyname2",
    "employees_array" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a34564c9beb3178555e9911"),
            "salary" : 25000,
            "employeename" : "employeename3",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98dc")
        }
    ],
    "products_array" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a3456929beb3178555e9920"),
            "price" : 400,
            "productname" : "productname2",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5a3455b69beb3178555e98dc")
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want these `salary >= 10000 and products having price >= 500` conditions you'd have to formulate your aggregation pipeline like this:

```
db.getCollection('companies').aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: "employees",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "company_id",
            as: "employees_array"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "company_id",
            as: "products_array"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            employees: {
                $map: {
                    input: {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$employees_array",
                            "as": "employee",
                            "cond": {
                                "$gte": ["$$employee.salary", 10000]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    as: "emp",
                    in: {
                        "salary": "$$emp.salary",
                        "name": "$$emp.employeename"
                        // You can add more fields
                    }
                }
            },
            products: {
                $map: {
                    input: {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$products_array",
                            "as": "product",
                            "cond": {
                                "$gte": ["$$product.price", 500]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    as: "prd",
                    in: {
                        "price": "$$prd.price",
                        "productname": "$$prd.productname"
                        // you can add more fields
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
])
```

If some arrays don't satisfy this `salary >= 10000` (for employees) or this `price >= 500` (for products) it is possible that you get 0 results, but that is normal.

Comment: Yes I was expecting same result and I am getting the list of companies but I am getting 0 results in `products_array` and `employees_array`. And I haven't put any conditions on `salary`/`price` of `products_array` and `employees_array` array yet as I want to test it without conditions first.

Comment: @DimpalSingh do you get any results at all? Even from a single collection?

Comment: No I am not getting even from a single collection

Comment: Ok, then this is your problem not the query. How do you connect to your database? If you connect directly on your mongo then this query shouldn’t be a problem

Comment: I am getting something like this:
`[{
    "_id" : "5a3455b69beb3178555e98da",
    "name" : "companyname1",
    "employees_array" : [ ],
},
{
    "_id" : "5a3455b69beb3178555e98dc",
    "name" : "companyname2",
    "employees_array" : [ ],
}]`

Comment: are your `_id`s of type objectId? Maybe your framework converts them to string and you have to change them back to objectid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161364/discussion-between-dimpal-singh-and-alex-p).